# How do I get the value of a useState hook from an imported component in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple react app that I made with a `create-react-app` command. It's pretty boilerplate but I added typescript. My App.tsx file looks like this:

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ToggleSwitch from "./ToggleSwitch";

function App() {
  const [resp, setResp] = useState("");

  async function callApi() {
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/hello`;
    const helloStream = await fetch(url);
    const helloText = await helloStream.text();
    setResp(helloText as string);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
      <ToggleSwitch />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div className="card">
        <button onClick={() => callApi()}>click this to call API</button>
        <p>{resp}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Notice how I'm using the imported component `<ToggleSwitch />` who's source code is in the file `ToggleSwitch.tsx` which looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./ToggleSwitch.css";

function ToggleSwitch() {
  const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState(false);
  const onToggle = () => setIsToggled(!isToggled);
  return (
    <label className="toggle-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked={isToggled} onChange={onToggle} />
      <span className="switch" />
    </label>
  );
}
export default ToggleSwitch;
```

As you can see from `ToggleSwitch.tsx`, I have a `useState` hook dictating whether or not the switch value "isToggled" is "true" or "false." How do I get the state of that switch value "isToggled" from the `App.tsx` file? It is crucial that i can access "isToggled" from `App.tsx` becuase I plan on putting the toggled boolean into the API call that `App.tsx` is performing on the button press that calls `callApi()`.

Comment: You could lift state up, use a reducer, or pass in an event to trigger from the child to the parent. See https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example

Comment: You'll need to define a function in App and pass that as a prop to ToggleSwitch, and then call the function in ToggleSwitch while passing state value as an argument. Have a look at thus: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-pass-data-from-child-to-parent

Comment: You can do something like this (https://tsplay.dev/wjXg8m). If that answers your question, I can write it up as an answer. If not, what did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So both App and ToggleSwitch need the isToggled state. A common practice to solve this is to lift the state up, meaning the App component will handle that piece of state.

```js
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ToggleSwitch from "./ToggleSwitch";

function App() {
  const [resp, setResp] = useState("");
  const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState(false);

  async function callApi() {
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/hello`;
    const helloStream = await fetch(url);
    const helloText = await helloStream.text();
    setResp(helloText as string);
  }
  console.log(isToggled);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
      <ToggleSwitch isToggled setIsToggled />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div className="card">
        <button onClick={() => callApi()}>click this to call API</button>
        <p>{resp}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";
import "./ToggleSwitch.css";

function ToggleSwitch({ isToggled, setIsToggled } : { isToggled: boolean, setIsToggled: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>> }) {
  const onToggle = () => setIsToggled(!isToggled);
  return (
    <label className="toggle-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked={isToggled} onChange={onToggle} />
      <span className="switch" />
    </label>
  );
}
export default ToggleSwitch;
```

Comment: I basically did exactly what you put here but I altered the files for typescript. This is what I put for `App.tsx` https://gist.github.com/ChristianOConnor/262716410f0ece6de2689a584fb60b70 and this is what I put for `ToggleSwitch.tsx` https://gist.github.com/ChristianOConnor/3b680ade37af2e6fcfed6917e4885c74. Could I edit/alter your answer for typescript and then accept it?

Comment: It’s not letting me edit the question… something about too many edits in the cue or something. Can you replace your code with the App.tsx and ToggleSwitch.tsx from my GitHub gists? And comment when you do that so I can accept the answer. Maybe it will let you edit the answer because you are the poster.

Comment: Now should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a useState hook from an imported component in a React app.
first you need to export your useState do in your the main file:

```
import {resp,setResp} from './App.js';

<ToggleSwitch resp={resp} setResp={setResp} />
```

after that go to ToggleSwitch and set parameters:

```
function ToggleSwitch({ resp, setResp }) {
//your code
}
```

I hope your probleme was solved.